# AWS - Does not recognise access key ID and secret access key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using AWS, boto3 and Pycharm to write a very simple program on python that compare one faces from one face image to another face from another face image.
I written the following simple source code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                    aws_access_key_id = "xxx",
                    aws_secret_access_key = "yyy")

BUCKET = "eyeglasses-images"
KEY_SOURCE = "Foucault.jpg"
KEY_TARGET = "Ricoeur.jpg"


def compare_faces(bucket, key, bucket_target, key_target, threshold=80, region="eu-west-1"):
    rekognition = boto3.client("rekognition", region)
    response = rekognition.compare_faces(
        SourceImage={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Name": key,
            }
        },
        TargetImage={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": bucket_target,
                "Name": key_target,
            }
        },
        SimilarityThreshold=threshold,
    )
    return response['SourceImageFace'], response['FaceMatches']


source_face, matches = compare_faces(BUCKET, KEY_SOURCE, BUCKET, KEY_TARGET)

# the main source face
print
"Source Face ({Confidence}%)".format(**source_face)

# one match for each target face
for match in matches:
    print
    "Target Face ({Confidence}%)".format(**match['Face'])
    print
    "  Similarity : {}%".format(match['Similarity'])
```

However I get the following error:

```
raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

(Obviously in the place of xxx and yyy I am using the real keys)

What is the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: If the value is a string then you need to surround it with quotes.

Comment: Thanks! See my edited post for the actual error which I am encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session first. Eg.

```
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

and then get your resource

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Note that aws_session_token is optional and will be used if you use STS to get temp sessions.

Just saying

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
```

will use default creds in `~/.aws/credentials` file. So it cannot be used in your case.

It would be good if you can directly use -

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    # Hard coded strings as credentials, not recommended.
    aws_access_key_id='xx',
    aws_secret_access_key='yy'
)
```

For more details refer - [boto3 configuration documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuring-credentials)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I get the SESSION_TOKEN?

Comment: It's optional. Don't provide it for your case.  It is used for temp session token that you use with STS.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will give it a try it. By the way, edit your post a bit because I am  not understanding the part "Just saying". Is that I must use either `s3 = session.resource('s3')` or `s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`? It is not very clear in the way you write it.

Comment: Also it is not very clear what is the role of `s3 = session.resource('s3')` in the sense that the program can run properly(?) even without it.

Comment: @Universalis my guess is it will try to pick credentials from `~/.aws.credentials`. You can try `aws configure` to setup default credentails and then  try your original way.

Comment: Hm, this it too time-consuming. The whole problem originates from the fact that it is not really clear when `session` or `client` or `resource` should be used in each case. (I would really like someone to explain me this)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the line: `rekognition = boto3.client("rekognition", region)`

Because you did not specify the keys here, boto3 is trying to find the credentials file in ~/.aws. Update this to use the `session` object as mentioned by Aniket. Your code should change to:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
)
rekognition = session.client("rekognition", region)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now this is fixed (but I have more coming!).

Comment: However I used  `boto3.Session` instead of `boto3.session.Session` .